# google-filestore file locks limit - How to monitor

Tags: google-cloud-stackdriver, file-locking, google-cloud-filestore

Filestore has a limit of 128 File Locks.

Are There Ways to monitor how many file lock? What happens if you reach this limit?

I checked on stack driver, but all metric haven't any link with file locks

Thank you very much for any suggestions.

Giorgio

(https://cloud.google.com/filestore/docs/limits)

A Cloud Filestore instance can have up to 128 file locks across all clients of the instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `lslocks` from the util-linux package as mentioned on [this other forum](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85994/how-to-list-processes-locking-file), the limit would not be shown on Stackdriver as it would need to monitor the files on your Filestore instance which Stackdriver doesn't do for privacy reasons.

If you reach the limit, it would mean that you would not be able to create another lock on the file (you would get an error when the 129th user or process tries to open it). You could ask for an increase to this limit to the GCP Support team, however, there is no guarantee that they will increase the limit.

Hope you find this helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You can not monitor the lock file in Stackdriver.

These are the metrics available for monitoring Filestore instance:

> Bytes written: Number of bytes written.
>
> Bytes read: Number of bytes read.
>
> Disk read operation count: Number of disk read operations. If the
>   Filestore instance caches the data, some read operations will not be
>   reflected as disk reads.
>
> Disk write operation count: Number of disk write operations. If the
>   Filestore instance caches the data, some write operations will not be
>   reflected as disk writes.
>
> Free disk bytes: Number of free disk bytes.
>
> Free disk bytes percent: Percentage of free disk bytes.
>
> Procedure call count: Returns the same information as the nfsstat -s
>   command.
>
> Time (in milliseconds) spent on disk read operations: Time spent on
>   disk reads.
>
> Time (in milliseconds) spent on disk write operations: Time spent on
>   disk writes.
>
> Used disk bytes: Number of used disk bytes.
>
> Used disk bytes percent: Percentage of used disk bytes.

The Filestore Engineer Team is considering including lock file as a new metric, but there is no ETA for it.

You can only open a ticket to Google Cloud Platform Support and ask for this metric [link](https://cloud.google.com/support/).

In case you reach the limit, the time to access the data will increase.

Please keep in mind that you can request additional quota using the Cloud Console. However limits cannot generally be increased unless specifically noted.

Comment: Please flag my answer as accepted for better visibility for community.